# How To Get The Variables of Equation

Tags: c, equation

I'm creating a program in **C** that need to print the **variables of any equation**, given by the user. For example, if the user digits the string (vector of char): "`2x + 3y + 4z = -8`", it has to print: "the variables are: `x, y and z`". How can I print these variables (letters)?

This is my actual **CODE**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXCHAR 1000

int main() {
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    int var = 0;
    char *cp;
    char *receivecp;
    char *variables;
    char *p;
    int numberOfEquations = 0;

        printf("Enter the equation: ");

        gets(str);
            printf("Equation's variables: ");

            for(cp=str; *cp; ++cp)
                if(isalpha(*cp)) //is letter
                {
                   printf("%c", *cp, "\n"); //print letter
                }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: start by replacing everything that is not a variable with a blank.

Comment: `scanf("%*s",MAXCHAR, str);`

Comment: Given the description of this question, I'm assuming this is some kind of school task. There's all sorts of questions popping into my head, such as what does `"2xy + 3zy"` mean, for instance, is that `2*x*y + 3*z*y`, or are you dealing with to variables named `xy` and `zy`. Assuming that we're only talking about single-letter variables here, what about a 26-element array, with one element per variable name, where the value is 0 if it is not used, and 1 if used, and then just looping through the expression to find each variable?

Comment: "`printf("%c", *cp, "\n");`" --> `printf("%c ", *cp);`

Comment: For instance, a question you will have to deal with is this: What if I type in `2x + 3x`? Should you list `x` twice?

Comment: When asking for help on your homework, post the assignment.

Comment: Does your code work? Did you even write it?